Mathematical Expression
How can I write -r² in anaconda environment?
I tried:

-1 * r**2
-1 * (r**2)
(-1) * (r**2)

None of these worked.
What do you think is the problem?

Please give an error message or something.  "This didn't work" isn't a lot to go on...

Write how and what do you mean by didn't work?

The error message is "invalid syntax"

This question is not about math/trigonometry/mathematical expression but about Python syntax. It would be nice if you can edit the tags and the title

Are you using Python or R? Cause R uses ^ and python uses ** or math.pow(), but if you are geting invalid syntax it kinda makes it feel like you are running R. What is the entire error message (maybe add a screenshot of exactly what you are doing)?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Since you have not said that it is a Python-related question but you use right Python expression I think you are

either have not started Python interpreter
you have not defined variable r

Anyway "does not work" is not helping description of the error. What exactly does the system show? What exactly do you run and which exactly commands you run there since activating the environment?

(base) ...>python
Python ... :: Anaconda, Inc. ...
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> r = 5
>>> -1 * (r ** 2)
-25


The error message is 'invalid syntax'

Python always shows something more than onlt "invalid syntax". Are you using Python?

Yes I am using Python

Thank you for all the suggestions, it works

@Maisalatee Then could you please accept the answer to show that the question is solved
